# Why did these Deep Space Nine characters have to part forever?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I didn't quite catch the idea / explanation for

> Odo leaving Kira forever

in the final episode of Star Trek: Deep Space Nine.

He managed to

> cure Female Changeling within a matter of seconds,

so why he wasn't able to

> cure entire The Great Link in a matter of days or months or so?

Why did his separation from

> Kira

have to be forever?

Comment: Other than that he finally had to get over her?

Comment: I think he explains pretty clearly, "Nerys, it's time I rejoined the Great Link." He needs to cure his people sure, but he has a personal need to rejoin his native culture.

Comment: I don't recall getting the impression it would be forever, just that he would be gone a while. I need to go back and re-watch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having Odo rejoin the Great Link was the more important to the Female Founder than taking over the Alpha Quadrant. She stated so herself during Season 6 Episode 5 "[Favor the Bold](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Favor_the_Bold_(episode))"

> Weyoun: "I must say, you're doing a wonderful job with Odo.'"
>
> Female Changeling: "Meaning what?!"
>
> W: "Meaning that he's always posed a potential threat to our plans, but you seem to have neutralized him quite nicely."
>
> FC: "Neutralize Odo?! Is that why you think I'm here?! Odo is a Changeling - bringing him home, returning him to the Great Link means more to us than the Alpha Quadrant itself. Is that clear?"

Since it would end the war, his doubts about long-term life with Nerys based on his time with Laas, and with the revelation that the Federation went to such lengths to annihilate his people, it makes sense he would decide that he needs to rethink his place in life and that rejoining the Link now is the next logical step.

Answer (score 4):

Odo, when rejoined the Great Link, did indeed heal it in a matter of seconds, unless there is an edited version of this episode that's missing a scene or something? I'm pretty sure there was change of color of the ocean from green to gold when he entered it...

Odo had to go back to teach the Great Link the true meaning of justice and love. It was clear from the scene of healing the Female Changeling that beside the physical healing there also was healing of the mind. Else her "Now I understand" and peaceful surrender to arrest is completely meaningless...

Comment: But, you answer doesn't change or explain anything. Both physical and mind-healing took place in a matter of seconds for Female Changeling and -- I think, we may assume -- would take the appropriate amount of time for the entire Great Link. You only extended question, that both kinds of healing was necessary, but in my opinion you bring no explanation on why both processes required forever or very, very long separation of Odo and Kira.

Comment: Oh? I agree - kind of - that some improvement to the answer may be needed. But you want to tell me that teaching the entire population of a planet - what took Odo his whole life to learn and, more importantly understand - is something done fast and easy? Not to mention it was the purpose of Odo's sendiing forth? Which means that he's to return to the Great Link eventually anyway. As for the Female Changeling - she was more advanced than the rest of them due to her interactions with Odo for years..

Comment: The entire population of the planet is 1 - with the great link it should be fast and easy.